# Concatenate dataframes after encoding

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I am trying to combine one array and a matrix.
Specifically the array includes numerical data (years), while the matrix contains encoded data.

The characteristics are as follows:

```
X_a=df.Year
Name: Year, Length: 5854, dtype: float64

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X_t = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Text'].replace(np.NaN, ""))
Out: <5854x8206 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 25871 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I tried as follows:

```
X= pd.concat([X_a, X_t], axis=1)
```

but I have got the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Could you please tell me if it is possible to concatenate back these two datasets and how to do it?

Data:

```
Year     Text
1999     _italic_
2000    add language identifier to highlight code
2004    escape put returns between paragraphs
```

...

Comment: before voting for closing, explaining me the reasons. I think I have provided all the information required for replicating an example of dataset that I am using and the essential code

Comment: thanks snakecharmerb. It think so, but since I am not familiar with these transformation I have followed what I have found on the web. I found that I could use pd.concat but I do not know how to transform the matrix into a different object :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages is basically telling you the problem. You can concatenate only pandas series and dataframes. SKLearn doesn't return those, but rather numpy arrays. In this case, moreover, it creates a sparse array.

There are several things you can do here, depending on ease of use vs. memory performance. Possibly the simplest would be use

```
X_t = pd.DataFrame(vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Text'].replace(np.NaN, "")).todense(), index=df.index)
```

but note that it creates a dense matrix and then dense dataframe.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and explanation, @Ami Tavory